# How to get a Common object from a table id?

Tags: axapta, x++, aot, dynamics-ax-2012

How to instantiate a common type object (the table's base class in AX) via a `TableId`?
Furthermore what else can we do with TableId?

My goal is to send `tableid` to my method and there, I will make the buffer of the table the id belongs to. Is it possible?

Comment: yes we can, here it is: 
http://www.doens.be/2009/07/select-a-record-from-a-table-when-you-only-have-the-tableid/ 

i was so desperate for answer,

Comment: You should answer your own question.

Answer (score 6):

It can be done like this:

```
public static Common makeRecord(TableId _tableId)
{
    return new DictTable(_tableId).makeRecord();
}
```

Comment: yes we can, here it is: 
http://www.doens.be/2009/07/select-a-record-from-a-table-when-you-only-have-the-tableid/

I was so desperate for answer

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do this. Here is a webpage explaining: 
http://www.doens.be/2009/07/select-a-record-from-a-table-when-you-only-have-the-tableid/